# gmail.com throws ERR_CONNECTION_REST

Tags: internet-connection

I'm unable to access gmail.com by simply typing the url into the search box, but seaching for it with a search engine and then visiting the website works. Hitting the url directly results in `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

Edit:
It occurs on every browser on my device. I tried mozilla firefox and chrome.

I'm using ubuntu 22.04.
mail.google.com works.

Output for nslookup gmail.com
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   gmail.com
Address: 172.217.166.165
Name:   gmail.com
Address: 2404:6800:4009:80e::2005

it resolves well apparently

I was using opendns earlier but chnaged to google dns but the problem still persits.
gmail.com in incognito is redirected to `https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/gmail/about/` but the normal window where I'm currenltly logged in throws `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

Apparently there is some issue with the opendns dns server, changing it to google or ISP dns fixes it.
I'd have figured it out sooner but I didn't know I needed to forget and reconnect to the network in order for the modified dns server to take effect, browser was still using the earlier dns even after changing the dns.

Comment: What you get in search isn’t `gmail.com` but `mail.google.com`, which is hosted on different servers.

Comment: ... and you didn't even bother to tell us what web browser you're using. i voted to close this question as "needs additional details". KDE Konqueror? Opera? Apple Safari? Mozilla Firefox? Microsoft Edge? Google Chrome? something else?

Comment: ah that's better. vote close retracted. what output do you get from running in a terminal `nslookup gmail.com`  ?  you might need to run `sudo apt install dnsutils;`  first

Comment: oh ok @DanielB, so that means gmail.com is apparently down?

Comment: nope, gmail.com is not down, and is working properly. my best guess at this point is that there's something strange with your ISP's DNS server. what output do you get from running in a terminal `nslookup gmail.com` ?

Comment: thanks @hanshenrik, i've included the output for nslookup

Comment: Configure your DNS to something other than your router or ISP and update your question (and not Google DNS).

Comment: your nslookup looks fine. what do you get from running `curl --insecure -H 'Host: gmail.com' 'https://172.217.166.165'`   ?  EDIT: i had a typo in "--insecure", fixed now.

Comment: @Ramhound actually his router DNS works fine. 172.217.166.165 is a legit gmail server ip

Comment: The author does not indicate what domain the search results are exactly.  The "connection reset error" (i.e. ERR_Connection_Reset) suggests a TLS issue. Google Chrome highly respects Google domains (built-in).

Comment: ERR_Connection_Reset usually means that a firewall is blocking the traffic or messing with protocol compliance (TLS). generally if the site doesn't respond at all, it takes about two minutes and returns a ERR_Connection_Timeout. so either something between you and gmail or the site itself is rejecting you actively.

Comment: thanks @Ramhound it was a dns problem afterall